# ES 7.14 show search profile debugging tool

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I'm using **ES 7.14 / Kibana 7.10**, my query is the following:

```
 var query = {
    "index": "my_index",
    "size": 10
};
var body = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*antonio* *banderas*",
                        "fields": [
                            "text"
                        ],
                        "default_operator": "and"
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
};
body.explain = false;
body.profile = true;
query.body = body;
const res = await client.search(query);
```

I have set to `true` the high-level `profile` flag to activate the [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html), but I do not see the `profile` field in the response object `res`, where `res` holds an array of results:

```
[{
    _index: 'my_index',
    _type: '_doc',
    _id: 'my_doc_id',
    _score: 2,
    _source: {}
}]
```

Comment: can you add the received response in your post please ?

Comment: @BouraouiKACEM thanks I have added the result from the client.

Comment: I think that You have a syntax error   "default_operator": "and",    remove the ","

Comment: Typo sorry, there wasn't in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_searchtemplate

or try with client.**helpers**

```
await client.helpers.search({
        index:indexName,
        body: esQuery
    });
```

there is no reason to not be returned expect an error within the api elasticsearch javascript

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `client.search` as it's defined `elasticsearch@15.5.0` I expect it should work ok. There is any `helpers` object on the `client` object in the nodejs client.